# Help with Jersey auto-generation of WADL

Tags: jersey, wadl

As described here: http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/WADL

I'm using Jersey 1.4 in Tomcat 6.

I have tried every possible URI with a "/application.wadl" and all I get is a 404 (not available).  I'm obviously not understanding something, but every blog I read makes it sound like this is "out of the box" functionality.  I'm using Tomcat 6..should this matter?

I was able to use Pavel's example on using the WadlResource object here, but it seems I shouldn't need to do this: http://markmail.org/message/lbeaw5vyr4qergdd#query:+page:1+mid:fo4dt7tbd6rb3gvi+state:results

thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution to this? i have the same problem with the note that it works just fine when deployed to jetty but it does not in tomcat.

Comment: I think I forgot to add the web application's name in the URL.  For example, if the web context name (name of your project directory in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps) is "foo", then I had to use http://localhost:8080/foo/servletMappingPattern

Answer (score 4):

I think that ChrisO most likely has the answer in that your wadl would be available at http://localhost:{port}/{warname}/application.wadl

Comment: This should be the right answer.  Worked well with Jersey 1.17.1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and found out that default application.wadl was only working when configured at the root of the app

My conf included several url patterns like the following

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey-spring</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

And I had to add this to make it work :

```
  <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>jersey-spring</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/application.wadl</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jersey, the WADL will be given automatically when you suffix the application.wadl to your url.

Here all the **/rest/** is the <url-pattern> for the <servlet-mapping>

```
http: // yourmacine:8080 / RESTfulExample/rest/application.wadl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the display-name and url-pattern of the sevlet mapping(if any) before application.wadl